# Why is the 5′ end of DNA a monophosphate?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics

According to my textbook:

> While the 5′ end of a DNA strand is typically a monophosphate, the 5′
> end of an RNA molecule is typically a triphosphate.

Source: *Biology: How Life Works, 3rd Edition*

How do we know the 5′ end of DNA a monophosphate? I understand that...

- DNA and RNA synthesis cleaves nucleoside triphosphates into nucleoside monophosphates to form the sugar-phosphate backbone.
- Necessarily, the first nucleotide will have three phosphates intact.

What I don't understand is why DNA doesn't have a triphosphate on the 5′ end like RNA. How does that happen?

Comment: Related but the answer states the opposite is true and has not been accepted by the asker: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81656/how-many-phosphates-are-in-the-5-end-of-a-dna-strand

Comment: My comment serves to show that I did my work by searching for an answer in a few places.

I didn't understand the linked answer, it was too specific of a response to a general question. Secondly, there was too little activity in the linked question so I couldn't trust its accuracy. Lastly, the answer contradicted the textbook, so I thought it was appropriate to ask a new question.

Comment: @David ...He is the original poster and I find your comment quite rude..

Comment: @Andrew — The original poster of the post the poster of this post referenced. I was explaining why if that post was a duplicate of this it made no difference whether an answer had been accepted or not. Indeed it makes no difference whether it has been answered or not. If you or someone managed to persuade a mod that was rude I can only shake my head in disbelief

Comment: The deleted comment: "Whether or not the poster has accepted an answer here is irrelevant. He didn’t know in the first place so he has no authority. It works better on the original computing site Stack Overflow, where the problem is generally practical, and one accepts the solution that works. The answer to the other question actually shows a table of different genomes, so is based on experimental evidence. Have you read it? Do you understand it. Perhaps like the original poster you didn’t realize the true complexity that your probably deficient text ignored. – David 2 hours ago"

Comment: This problem wouldn't arise in bacterial chromosomes, plasmids and other circular DNA molecules, for a circle has no ends. :P As far as eukaryotic chromosomes are concerned, they have telomeres. I think reading about telomeres and the associated replication machinery from http://www.hammiverse.com/lectures/16/4.html should answer your question.

Comment: I only saw your post by chance. To draw someone's attention to a post other than the poster of a question or answer you need to preface their handle by @ . The question of reviving duplicates — answered or unanswered, accepted or unaccepted belongs on Meta. As I guessed, you didn't understand the linked answer because — from the nature of your text you are study biology, rather than molecular biology — and you would be unlikely to know about the detailed chemistry of the initiation of RNA and DNA synthesis. To say so is hardly rude.

Comment: ...However the important thing for you is to help you understand your book, and for anyone who wishes to help you they need to know the context of what appears a strange statement in a book published recently. So can you perhaps give an indication of the title of the section this appears in and what follows this statement. The reason one finds this strange is that "a typical DNA strand" is unclear. I would take it to mean the ends of a chromosome — as does the linked reference. Likewise the end of an RNA molecule depends on whether it is mature and what type of RNA it is. Can you clarify?

Comment: The quoted text is from chapter 3 (nucleic acids & transcription) section 2 (DNA structure) a sentence or two after describing the nucleotides used in RNA, but before any description of transcription. It doesn't assume eukaryote/prokaryote either. I think typical may mean lacking edge cases, but I recognize biology is full of them. I interpret the text as meaning if you follow such a typical strand to its 5' end you will encounter a monophosphate and then no more nucleotides. My confusion is why this isn't a triphosphate.